# How to make the kendo grid editable when using the rowTemplate in grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the rowTemplate in kendo grid. I did not found any correct sample for editing sample (using row template) is there is anyway to do edit the cell when using the rowtemplate in kendo grid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted a simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbristowe/WMyYL/).